# Unable to construct java object from json

Tags: json, jackson, gson

Can any body tell me Java class structure equivalent to below json:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": 
    {
        "group_id":2758,
        "0":
        {
            "id": "2758-1",
            "customid": "1",
            "customid1": "",
            "customid2": "",
            "mobile": "9190********",
            "status": "AWAITED_DLR",
        },
        "1":
        {
            "id": "2758-2",
            "customid": "2",
            "customid1": "",
            "customid2": "",
            "mobile": "9190********",
            "status": "AWAITED_DLR",
        }
            ...
    }
    "message": "Campaign Submitted successfully"
}
```

Unable to decide the structure of `data` object as it contains `group_id` and list of other object.

Comment: "data" contains "group_id" and objects that has "id", "customid", "customid1"...

Comment: yes ..as you say "data" contains  "group_id" and objects that has "id", "customid", "customid1"

Comment: Indeed. That should be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a first class which represents your structure with :

- an Int : group_id
- an ArrayList : data, that contains objects of type Item

Then you create the second class Item that represents the structure of "0" and "1".

If you want to keep the label "0", "1" you can make the type of data an `Hashmap<String,Item>` instead of ArrayList.

Comment: "0" and "1" are not labels they are indices which may become 3,4,5 if more objects are threre

Comment: So use an `ArrayList` you could access data via indexes with this type of list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map:

```
class Data {
   int group_id;
   Map<Integer, InnerObject> map = new HashMap<>();
}

Data data = new Data();
data.group_id = 2758;
data.map.put(0, innerObject0);
data.map.put(1, innerObject1);
```